# having problems with Invision Community Board when posting/editing, getting a "EX0" error

Tags: php, mariadb, invision-power-board

first question i've asked on this site, here goes.

For those of you who would rather just see what we are working with here.

- Host: hostinger.com
- Php: 7.0.33
- mySQL: 5.5.5-10.2.17-MariaDB
- Forum version: Invision Community v4.3.6

So, I, manage a forums using invision community, I have extensively searched (being honest only really used google), but I have tried nonetheless.
Our host is hostinger (from what i’ve gathered through light research and my own experiences working with them on this site, they aren't exactly the best option but it's what we got)

we had recently done an update (from 4.2 to 4.3 i believe) but the error had started before we did an update.
the particular error i've received is a "EX0"
worst part about this error, is it "was" seemingly isolated to newer areas to the forums it is starting to affect all of them.

here are a few samples of errors i've had
https://pastebin.com/xkkLyUb5

```
InvalidArgumentException:  (0)
#0 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/system/Content/Search/Index.php(120): IPS\_Task::queue('core', 'IndexSingleItem', Array, 5, true)
#1 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/system/Content/Item.php(2049): IPS\Content\Search\_Index->indexSingleItem(Object(IPS\forums\Topic))
#2 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/applications/forums/sources/Topic/Topic.php(1091): IPS\Content\_Item->unhide(NULL)
#3 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/applications/forums/sources/Topic/Topic.php(616): IPS\forums\_Topic->unhide(NULL)
#4 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/applications/forums/sources/Topic/Topic.php(572): IPS\forums\_Topic->processAfterCreateOrEdit(Array)
#5 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/applications/forums/modules/front/forums/topic.php(496): IPS\forums\_Topic->processAfterEdit(Array)
#6 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/system/Dispatcher/Controller.php(85): IPS\forums\modules\front\forums\_topic->edit()
#7 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/system/Content/Controller.php(50): IPS\Dispatcher\_Controller->execute()
#8 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/applications/forums/modules/front/forums/topic.php(39): IPS\Content\_Controller->execute()
#9 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/system/Dispatcher/Dispatcher.php(146): IPS\forums\modules\front\forums\_topic->execute()
#10 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/index.php(13): IPS\_Dispatcher->run()
#11 {main}

Backtrace
#0 /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/forums/init.php(537): IPS\_Log::log('InvalidArgument...', 'uncaught_except...')
#1 [internal function]: IPS\IPS::exceptionHandler(Object(InvalidArgumentException))
#2 {main}
```

some things i've tried (may or may not have thought it relevant, but nonetheless it didn't work)

- Cleared my browser cookies (it happened idk if it was relevant)
- Cleared my browser cache
- Switching task method to Cron (surprisingly without breaking anything)
- Disabled Enable Friendly URLs
- Enabled Enable Friendly URLs
- Tried Rewrite URLs
- Cleared the server’s cached data (happened through the automated support tool)

I barely have any background in this stuff, but any additional information that's needed feel free to ask for.

Comment: you should be seeking support for the writers of the software, not here

Comment: currently working with communicating with the owner of the forums, which takes a while, and the software owners only communicate with direct clients, so when it comes to problems I have to go else where.

Comment: What is the error when you are in and out of `DEV_MODE`?

Comment: Any chance that this error started after a database migration or change servers?

Comment: there has been no movement of anything, besides the update, as far as I know.

Comment: @RickKraut It seems like an issue with the indexing task. You could try to disable it or figure out what happened to it. Also reuploading that task file could help solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to a corrupted extension in your `core` application.

---

if you look at the function `queue` in `\IPS\Task` (`/system/Task/Task.php`)

It has the following conditions that can throw an `InvalidArgumentException`:

```
try
{
    $extensions = \IPS\Application::load( $app )->extensions( 'core', 'Queue', FALSE );
}
catch ( \OutOfRangeException $e )
{
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
}
if ( !isset( $extensions[ $key ] ) )
{
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
}
```

This will attempt to load each applications Queue extensions (stored in `/applications/APP_NAME/extensions/core/Queue`.

If for any reason it fails to load one of those, or the supplied extension does not exist for the specified application, it will throw this exception.

I would look at your `/applications/core/extensions/core/Queue` directory for any corrupted Queue Extensions, and possibly re-upload the entire directory in case some or all of them are missing.